# How to divide a div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a question with jQuery.

For example, I have the following structure:

```
<div class="page">
    <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
    ...
</div>
```

I need to turn it into:

```
<div class="page">
    <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>
<div class="page">
    <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>
...
```

Dividing the div into two (or more). How should I do?

Comment: you did it already

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Divide only based on `<p>` tags?

Comment: you need some JS code showing that you are trying..

Comment: @Varun any tags, but .children() should solve, should not it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop each `p` and then dinamicaly add new `div` and append that `p`

```js
$('div p').each(function(ix, el){
  var tmp = $('<div class="page"/>');
  $('body').append( $(tmp).append( $(el) ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
    <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) and then again [`wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) the elemnts in `<div class="page"></div>`

```js
function splitDiv() {
  $("p").unwrap().wrap("<div class='page'></div>");
}
```

```css
.page {
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>



<button onclick="splitDiv()">Split into diffrent <b>Divs</b></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **dynamically you can divided Html tag. i am just modify some code. Thanx.**

```js
function splitHtml(tag1,tag1class, tag2) {
  $(tag2).unwrap().wrap(tag1);
}
```

```css
.page {
  border: 2px dotted gray;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>



<button onclick="splitHtml('<div class=page>','page','p')">Split into diffrent <b>Divs</b></button>

<button onclick="splitHtml('<H1 class=page>','page','p')">Split into <b>H1</b></button>
```